# How Do I Use a ACF Custom Field To Add A Slider ID?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

```
soliloquy( the_field( 'slider' ) );
```

This is my code to add the ID for a slider from a ACF number field to a slider function call however it outputs the ID and doesn't execute the soliloquy function.

I think it might have something to do with the single qoutes.

Not sure how to wrap the slider ID in single qoutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **get_field()** function instead. It will RETURN the value instead of printing.
So, your code will be:

```
soliloquy( get_field( 'slider' ) );
```

Comment: Simple as that. Any reason the ACF function is better than using get_post_meta?

Comment: Sure. It's uniformity and shortage. One function to get posts meta, terms meta, users meta etc. Also, there is the option to create **options page** lol. And it serializes / deserializes automatically. So less things to take care about.

Answer (score 0):

This works but i prefer to use the ACF specific custom field function

```
soliloquy( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slider', true ) );
```